# Scrollbar on div broken html5

Tags: html

I have just done a quick sample of something I do not understand in html. The scrollbar for the content div is broken, and I don't know why… any ideas?

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/Fj3hJ7vY

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be please little more specific, about what do you want to achieve?

Comment: It does not scroll - you can see the test (lore ipsum etc.) overlaps the end of the div and the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its broken, looks like the problem is that you got nothing to scroll due too

```
<div class="content" style="height: 10000px;">
```

Try to change the height to a lower value. Try 575px instead.